# Problems with footer bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap, Is there are any classes for footer? Because I can't make it to stay on bottom. Here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18578/. This is footer css:

```
.footer-no-nav {
    border-top: 1px solid #C2B8B8;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the picture when I use bootstrap class navbar-fixed-bottom
[image]

Here is when the window resized:
[image]

Fixed my problem, no need any navbar-fixed-bottom:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are after a Sticky Footer.

Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18589/

The css relies on a removing the total height of the footer from the `margin-top` to make the footer stick to the bottom unless there is enough content to push it further. For a 40px height + 1px border-top footer this would calculate our margin-top to equal -41px.

```
footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #C2B8B8;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:-41px;
}

body,html{
    height:100%;
}
.container{
    min-height:100%;
}

<body>
  <div class="container">main content can go here</div>
  <footer>sticky footer content is stuck here</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just fixed my problem, no need any navbar-fixed-bottom:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `navbar-fixed-bottom` class to fixed it to the bottom like this:

```
<footer class="footer-no-nav navbar-fixed-bottom" role="contentinfo">
    <!--content-->
</footer>
```

**N.B.** You will have to give a background-color to the footer div and add a `margin-bottom` equivalent to the height of the footer to prevent elements from being covered by the footer.

Comment: When i make him fixed, he jump on the other content when window is resized.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with the above class name added: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/fNPvf/18583/ I can't seem to find this jumping you're referring to when resizing @McLaren

Comment: Look at the picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/LZ7FE.jpg NOT at the content AT ALL :D

Comment: The background-color is optional btw. But the margin-bottom for body is a must.

Comment: There is a trick to not allow footer to jump on other content. Use few <br /> before footer, so even if footer is resized to very small it will not cover your page content.

Comment: That's a good idea too but I think a `margin-bottom` would be a better alternative as @McLaren get's more flexibility in deciding the space between the footer and the content.

Answer (score 0):

This work for my webpage

```
<div class="panel-footer navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

Comment: You dont need to use navbar-inverse class it is just for different color of footer.

Comment: It's still fixed. I don't want it to be fixed. :/

Answer (score 0):

try to add div for all your contain

```
.all    {
    min-height:750px;

    }
```

and this is the link for your footer https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/18587/